# Printing time elapsed to Debug.log with a Coroutine is not working as I thought

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

New to programming in C# and Unity.
I had to work a bit with Coroutines, and played around a bit.
I thought the code would log the time every 2.0f seconds as indicated by the parameter, but it prints it a lot more !
The stopCoroutine code works fine.
Could someone explain me why this is happening,please.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _stopCoRoutine;

    private IEnumerator CoRoutine()
    {
        while (!_stopCoRoutine)
        {
            Debug.Log(Time.time.ToString("F2"));
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2.0f);
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CoRoutine());

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            _stopCoRoutine = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Crispi

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a new coroutine at every frame.
You should call `StartCoroutine(CoRoutine());` at `Start()`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that ;) 
The strange thing is that when I put it inside an if {} statement, it works as I thought it would work, and the script can still execute code that comes after the if {} statement.

```
> private void Update()
>     {
>         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad0))
>         {
>             StartCoroutine(PrintTotalTime());
>         }
> 
>         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
>         {
>             StopPrintTotalTime();
>             StartCoroutine(SpeedUp());
>         }
>     }
```

Here it starts and logs every 2 seconds and stops when the other one starts.
Is this because once it starts in the if {} statements, it stays there until stopped ?

Comment: There seems to be some missing code here, but it's pretty much the same.
You are starting a new coroutine every frame Keypad0 is pressed and starting a new coroutine every frame Space is pressed too.
Probably when you press Space you are also stopping those multiple coroutines started when you pressed Keypad0.

Comment: Yep, very true ! I know it's quite nonsencical, I was just trying to understand how Corroutines work :) 
Is there a way to check how many Coroutines are started up ?

and Thanx

Comment: I don't think there is a builtin way to know how many coroutines are running, but you sure can store them in a `List` and get the count at any time.
It should be enough to know that everything inside the `Update` method will run at every frame, and if you are using `StartCoroutine`, it sure will start another coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

found a way to prevent starting new Coroutines ! Prabably very silly, but I learned a lot doing all this ! Noob feeling happy :)

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad0) && !_0pressedAlready)
        {
            _0pressedAlready = true;
            StartCoroutine(PrintTotalTime());
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !_spacePressedAlready)
        {
            _spacePressedAlready = true;
            StopPrintTotalTime();
            StartCoroutine(SpeedUp());
        }
    }
```